# How to pass an integer array into a Razor function?

Tags: c#, arrays, razor

I am writing a function to select 3 articles from a JSON feed at random. I have created a function which generates a random number between 2 given end points and I have a for loop which iterates 3 times to output article content on to the page.

The random number function is working successfully, and the for loop does output article info to the page. The randomNumber function needs to run 3 times to get 3 random numbers and I need to ensure that once randomNumber1 has been picked, it can't be picked again. So I have created an array (featuredStories) to store picked numbers but am having trouble passing it into my getRandomNumber function.

```
@{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    var featuredStories = new List<int>();
}


@functions {
    public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max, Random rnd, int[] featuredStories) {

    int randomNumber = rnd.Next(min, max);

    if (featuredStories.Contains(randomNumber)){
        randomNumber = getRandomNumber(min, max, rnd);
    }else{
        featuredStories.Add(randomNumber);
    }


    return randomNumber;
}


@for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

    int randomNo = getRandomNumber(1, items.Count(), rnd, featuredStories);
}
```

I am currently getting an error:

**Razor syntax error. No overload for method 'getRandomNumber' takes 3 arguments**

Comment: The worst thing Microsoft ever did (yes ever) is allow functions in Razor. Razor is a view binding language, it should not contain logic. Move the logic into your controller and build a view model. Then you don't have this problem and your code has better separation of concerns.

Comment: @Liam Can you explain how is it that moving this code to a Controller removes this problem? Also, ASPX is much worse than Razor functions.

Comment: you'd get a compile error that'd tell you what the issue is. My main exception though is MVC is a design pattern that Microsoft have hijacked. The view should never contain logic, a function is logic.The design pattern says this is wrong. Tl'Dr follow the actual rules of MVC and you code will be easier to understand/maintain and you will get less bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two errors in fact:

```
@functions {
    public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max, Random rnd, (2) int[] featuredStories) {

    int randomNumber = rnd.Next(min, max);

    if (featuredStories.Contains(randomNumber)){
        randomNumber = getRandomNumber(min, max, rnd); (1)
    }else{
        featuredStories.Add(randomNumber);
    }


    return randomNumber;
}
```

1. The first error is that you are not passing  `featuredStories` in the recursive call.
2. The second error is that  `int[]` (which is a shortcut to `Array<int>`) does not have an `Add` method, and you also defined `featuredStories` as a `List<int>` at the top of the page.

So, to fix these, change your method to this:

```
@functions {
    public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max, Random rnd, List<int> featuredStories) {

    int randomNumber = rnd.Next(min, max);

    if (featuredStories.Contains(randomNumber)) 
    {
        randomNumber = getRandomNumber(min, max, rnd, featuredStories); 
    }
    else
    {
        featuredStories.Add(randomNumber);
    }


    return randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Camilo. Once you pointed out that an array can't have extra items added to it I changed the type to a List already. Everything is working now. Thanks again.

Comment: @JamesHowell Arrays can have extra items, but there is no easy way (you define the length upon instatiation). When you do know the length, use Array, when you don't, use List

Answer (score 2):

You've defined your function as:

```
public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max, Random rnd, int[] featuredStories) {
```

That's 4 arguments

But then inside that function, it calls itself with only 3 arguments:

```
randomNumber = getRandomNumber(min, max, rnd);
```

c# can't find another definition of the `getRandomNumber` function that has 3 arguments, hence the error.

Think carefully about what you're expecting this code to do.. To me it doesn't make sense, as written - code that is self documenting uses descriptive names for variables and functions and reading it should basically spell out the algorithm. When I read that code, i've no idea why a function that produces a random number would take a list of featured stories as an argument. If the function were called getRandomStory perhaps... ? And then I wonder - what is a story, and why does generating a random number sometimes result in the number becoming a story and sometimes not? And in the case when it doesnt, what is expected to be gained by calling the random number function again, omitting the list of stories?

Impossible to decipher that code; you'll come back to it in 6 months and think "whut??". If you're looking to get deeper into the nuts and bolts of any programming language, it's a good tactic to start with, to write out the algorithm in comments:

```
//get a random story from the known ones, but include a chance that a new random number can become a story
//generate a random number
//if it's in the known list, just return it
//if not in the list, add it and return it
```

Why do this? well.. All your life you've thought in english, so reason the algorithm out in english.. Then translate it to c#. Finally, if the c# is clear and well named, the comments will largely be redundant and can be deleted. Some obscure code might benefit from retaining the comment that spelled it out, but really that's a candidate for simplifying the code so it looks less like a code golf puzzle* and more like something you'd be delighted to maintain even if you didn't write

*for example, would you want to maintain this?

```
//return the first occurrence of a repeated int 
a=>{for(int p=0,q=0;;q++)while(p++<q)if(a[q]==a[p])return a[q];}
```

Comment: and if this was in the controller it wouldn't of compiled and you wouldn't have had this problem.

Comment: Guys I did stress that I am not a C# developer. I'm a FE developer trying to use a C# CMS. Be gentle.

Comment: I have renamed featuredStories to selectedNumbers so it more closely related to random number generation. I have added the 4th argument to the function call so thanks for that pointer. I am now getting an error 'Razor syntax error. 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found'. How do I add an item to an array in C#. I followed the following post for my first attempt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126759/add-item-to-string-array-in-razor-view

Comment: You don't; in c# arrays are a fixed length when declared and you don't add new elements to them. You can only set the value of an existing slot in the array, to something. If you want to Add() try making your function argument that is an `int[]` a `List<int>` instead

Comment: @JamesHowell That's because `Add` is a method of `List`, not `Array`. Change `getRandomNumber` to .... `List<int> selectedNumbers`

Comment: Thanks Camilo. All working now. Much appreciated. Good to know that arrays work differently in C# to Javascript. Thanks again.